# Sum of Roots Of Unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was looking at this page: [Elements of finite order in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164963/elements-of-finite-order-in-sl-2-mathbbz)

In the answer by Matt E he says that "ζ+ζ¯ being an integer" means that the cosine of theta must be an integer or a half integer but I can't see for the life of me see why. Would anyone be able to explain?

I tried drawing it as a triangle and related the edges using cosine, but I couldn't see a definitive reason that it must be some multiple of 1/2.

Edit: I get that 2 * real part means the real part is some multiple of 1/2, but then, to me, this suggests that the root of unity multiplied by cos(theta) has the same restriction, not cos(theta) itself?

Edit 2: Let me rephrase. Call the root a+ib. Then, adding it to its conjugate we get 2a which must be an integer. This I understand. To me, I then get this is hcos(theta), not cos(theta). Am I missing a property of h? I know this is a basic question, but I just don't understand...

Edit 3: Answered, as h must be 1.

Comment: $\zeta + \overline{\zeta} = 2\operatorname{Re} \zeta$. If $2w \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $w$ is an integer or a half-integer.

Comment: Because $2\Re(z)=z+\bar{z}$?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why that proves it... I did a triangle with sides a (the real part) and b, hypotenuse alpha and therefore, from what I understand, a must be some multiple of 1/2. But then a is alpha cos (theta), so why must cos(theta) have the same restriction?

Comment: Do you denote $h = |a+ib|$ ? If you do, then in the case you're considering $h = 1$ (because roots of unity are on the unit circle).

Comment: Oh my god... Yes... Thank you. :S That's extremely obvious.

Comment: You should write down yourself an answer :-)

Comment: Write down myself an answer to...?

Comment: To your question.

Comment: I don't understand. :P I tried, but got lost with the h. Now I get it, the solution is there. Do you mean, write the solution as an edit to the question above so others can see?

Comment: No, write the answer as an answer to the question.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realise I had that option. Doing now. :D

Answer (score 2):

Take a root of unity. Then it has the form a+ib, with its conjugate being a-ib. From the question, we are given that their sum must be an integer. That is, (a+ib + a-ib) = 2a is an integer. That is, a must be some integer multiple of one-half.

Thinking about this in terms of a triangle on an Argand diagram, we have that cos(theta) = a/c and, as it is a root of unity and must lie on the unit circle, we have that c=1. So, cos(theta) = a and must therefore be some integer multiple of one-half.